# Would you have done this pantry construction differently?

Tags: kitchens, cabinets, plywood

We're building a pantry in a small kitchen opening (about 1' depth, 6.5' height) and the original construction framing is anything but straight.

Nice cabinet-grade plywood is being used. Unfortunately there are gaps because the plywood was not shimmed before being nailed to the existing framing.

- My contractor plans to insert thin strips to fill the gaps.
- I am considering asking for him to take off the installed plywood, shim as necessary, and install again, since the thin strips may look obviously out of place.
- Or, we can use veneer to cover up the entire surface area, including strips/gaps, but this adds even more work and would cover up the nice plywood.

How would you approach this?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I would say that your contractor / carpenter is a rank amateur. If this was my project I would be mad at myself for selecting that contractor and as such would eat the investment so far, fire contractor and find someone you can trust to do good work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did he build it in place? I would've  built it first, then installed it. That way you know it is squared up. You could use shim to plum and level the pantry. I would have him do it over

Comment: Thanks. Yes, this was built in place unfortunately